# System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime not found in LINQPad 5

Tags: linq, linqpad

I have done a LINQ query in LINQPad 5. In the where clause of this query I am using  System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime function on a DateTime data type in order to remove the time.
For some reason LINQPad is not recognizing System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime despite of I have added the reference System.Data.Entity.dll in Additional references tab in LINQPad:

[image]

LINQPad show below error:

> CS0234: The type of namespace name 'DbFunctions' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data.Entity.dll'(are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a reference to EntityFramework.dll - I used the one from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

Comment: @NetMage thanks it worked